# How to do an if statement on a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I just realized that you can't just use an if statement on a function, for example this doesn't work:

```
function sayHello()
{
    echo "Hello World";
}

if(sayHello())
    echo "Function Worked";
else
    echo "Function Failed";
```

I also saw that a function can't be put as the value of a variable. So how can I do an if statement to check if a function has executed properly and display it to the browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working since `sayHello()` doesn't return anything place `return true` in there or something.

Comment: return true works, thanks. But the problem of the function repeating itself inside the if statement is present here too. It says "Hello WorldHello World" in the browser.

Comment: @Bruce:  I've copied & pasted the code you show and tested it (with PHP 5.2.9).  I'm only getting one "Hello World".  Are you sure you are not calling sayHello() a second time or doing something else to cause the "Hello World" to appear twice?

Comment: @Bruce you're probably calling the function twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (sayHello() === FALSE)
    echo "Function Failed";
else
    echo "Function Worked";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just one thing though, the function is repeated again inside the if statement, so there is "Hello WorldHello World" displayed in the browser.

Can this be done without the function repeating itself inside the if statement.

Comment: I don't know why "Hello World" is repeating. If you call `sayHello()`, it will print "Hello World". I am not sure what you want to do. If you want to print "Hello World" why don't you just call `sayHello()`. Btw shouldn't you up vote since it worked?

Answer (score -1):

this will work

```
<?php

$name1 = "bobi";

function hello($name) {
if($name == "bobi"){
    echo "Hello Bob";
  } else {
      echo "Morning";
    }
}

hello($name1);
?>
```

Comment: this is an incorrect solution to the question asking to check the result of a function in order to process further parsing

Answer (score -1):

```
function selam($isim)
{
    if ($isim == 'ugur') {
        return 'Selam '.$isim.' :)';
    }

    return 'Sen kimsin kardes?';
}

echo selam('ugur');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.